# Testing onClick handler with Enzyme - cannot trigger function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have a component that looks like such:

```
export default class RowCell extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    const { column } = this.props;
    const colClass = column.toLowerCase();
    return (
      <td className={`cell cell-row ${colClass === 'someval' ? 'anotherval' : colClass}`}>
        { this.renderAppropriateCell(colClass) }
      </td>
    );
  }
}
```

And I'm testing an onClick to see if it can properly fire the handler when a click is simulated. In this case the handler is setting/updating a piece of state.

```
it('Should fire the onClick handler', () => {
    const componentWithHandlerWrapper = shallow(
      <RowCell {...props} onClick={() => this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked })} />
    );
    // In this case, we are passing a dummy function that sets a piece of state in the component
    const rowCellInstance = componentWithHandlerWrapper.setState({ clicked: false });
    expect(rowCellInstance.instance().state.clicked).toEqual(false);

    rowCellInstance.simulate('click');
    expect(rowCellInstance.instance().state.clicked).toEqual(true);
  });
```

However I can't get the handler to set/update state on the shallow render of the component. The last expect is failing since either 1) the click simulation is not properly executing or 2) the click simulation works but cannot update state on a shallow render? I've tried it on an instance as well with no luck.

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: can you set the state to not false? and check if its equal false? that way we can check that the state of the component is functioning and can narrow down the debugging

Comment: where's the `onClick` prop used within your component? You need to attach the handler to an html element that gets rendered in RowCell and then simulate a click on that element (rather than on RowCell). It won't get called if you just pass it into a component as a prop and then simulate a click on that component

Comment: I think you need to add `onClick={this.props.onClick}` to the td element and then simulate the click like this: `rowCellInstance.find('td').simulate('click')`

Comment: Thank you for the comments @BillyReilly. You're right, however it seems that whatever function I pass that uses `this.setState({ clicked: false })` cannot be bound to the component instance. `this` always comes up undefined, even if the function is bound inline like so `<RowCell onClick={onClickHandler.bind(this) />`

Comment: Okay I've just noticed you're passing `onClick={() => this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked })}` into the component you're trying to test. When this.props.onClick() gets called this will try to update the state in the _parent_ of RowCell (which doesn't exist)

Comment: If you're trying to check that a click on the td can update the state of RowCell then you need to define your onClickHandler as a method of RowCell and then attach `onClick={ this.onClickHandler }` to the td element. You don't need to pass in a prop to do this

Comment: Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head @Billy Reilly